# Getting PERMISSION DENIED while copying a file from local to remote using SCP

Tags: linux, ssh, local, remote-access, scp

I am trying to copy a file from local machine to remote machine using `scp` using the following command:

```
scp user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/user/Testing.txt user@mm.mm.mm.mm:~/
```

and I ended up with following error:

```
Address xx.xx.xx.xx maps to ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.yyyy.yyyy.yyyyy.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Guide me with this error.

Comment: You don't need to specify user explicitly from the local machine. This will work if you are working as root user but otherwise it will give permission denied error. Also you are trying to copy the file to the remote machine's root folder which is not allowed. Try copying it somewhere else.

Comment: Use `scp /home/user/Testing.txt user@mm.mm.mm.mm:/home/user`

Answer (score 0):

Try to scp the file to the home folder.

```
    scp user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/user/Testing.txt user@mm.mm.mm.mm:.
```

This will copy the file to the home folder. If the above fails, in case of ec2 instances use 
identity file for the access. Identity file is available when the ec2 instance is being created and make sure the permission for this file is 400.

```
    scp -i identity_file.pem user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/user/Testing.txt user@mm.mm.mm.mm:.
```

Comment: thanks Bijendra... i am using ec2 instances, i have added access file as you mentioned and again the same error is thrown

Comment: are you able to ssh to the remote m/c

Comment: create a new pair of keys and try with that. That should work